# std::unique_ptr adapter class template for libgit2 objects

Tags: c++, template, pointers, git, raii

I'm working on a personal project to build an open-source gui for git. I'm hoping to learn a lot from the project, and maybe produce something useful for folks as I do.

I'm making use of [libgit2](https://libgit2.org/) to interface with git repositories. The library is implemented in C, and any time a new object is created (be it a commit, repository, branch, generic object) it's done by making a call into the library and passing a pointer to a pointer of where that object will be stored (foo**), and then these objects are deleted by the client code by making another libgit2 call to free the resource (e.g. git_repository_open and git_repository_free)

I want to get all the benefits of RAII types like std::unique_ptr but also make use of this library. Because we're using libgit2 function calls to create and destroy objects instead of the new, delete operators, I wrote my own adapter class to and make the calls to the right libgit2 functions but manage the created pointer in a std::unique_ptr:

https://github.com/StephenLHern/fons/blob/main/git/unique_libgit_ptr.hpp

```
#pragma once

#include <functional>
#include <git2.h>
#include <memory>

namespace fons::git
{
    template <typename T>
    class unique_libgit_ptr
    {
      public:
        template <class CreateMethodT, class... CreateMethodArgs>
        unique_libgit_ptr(CreateMethodT creator, std::function<void __cdecl(T *)> free_method, CreateMethodArgs &&...args)
        {
            T *rawPtr{};
            int createResult = creator(&rawPtr, std::forward<CreateMethodArgs>(args)...);

            if (createResult != GIT_OK)
                return;

            base_ptr = std::unique_ptr<T, std::function<void __cdecl(T *)>>{std::move(rawPtr), free_method};
        }

        T &operator*()
        {
            return &base_ptr;
        }

        T *operator->()
        {
            return *base_ptr;
        }

        operator bool()
        {
            return static_cast<bool>(base_ptr);
        }

        auto release()
        {
            return base_ptr.release();
        }

        auto reset(std::unique_ptr<T, std::function<void __cdecl(T *)>>::pointer ptr)
        {
            return base_ptr.reset(ptr);
        }

        auto get()
        {
            return base_ptr.get();
        }

        auto get_deleter()
        {
            return base_ptr.get_deleter();
        }

      private:
        std::unique_ptr<T, std::function<void __cdecl(T *)>> base_ptr;
    };

    using unique_commit_ptr = unique_libgit_ptr<git_commit>;
    using unique_revwalk_ptr = unique_libgit_ptr<git_revwalk>;
    using unique_git_obj_ptr = unique_libgit_ptr<git_object>;
    using unique_repo_ptr = unique_libgit_ptr<git_repository>;
    using unique_branch_itr = unique_libgit_ptr<git_branch_iterator>;
    using unique_ref_ptr = unique_libgit_ptr<git_reference>;

} // namespace fons::git
```

Here's how this class gets used, (unique_repo_ptr, unique_git_obj_ptr, unique_commit_ptr, etc.):

https://github.com/StephenLHern/fons/blob/main/git/commands/revwalk.cpp

```
#include "revwalk.hpp"
#include "app_main.hpp"

#include "git/git_observer.hpp"
#include "git/gitlib_manager.hpp"
#include "git/unique_libgit_ptr.hpp"

namespace fons::git
{
    wxDEFINE_EVENT(EVENT_REVWALK, revwalk_event);

    void revwalk::execute()
    {
        gitlib_manager gitlib;
        unique_repo_ptr repo(git_repository_open, git_repository_free, app->settings.active_repo.c_str());

        unique_revwalk_ptr walk(git_revwalk_new, git_revwalk_free, repo.get());

        if (!walk.get())
            return;

        git_revwalk_sorting(walk.get(), GIT_SORT_TOPOLOGICAL | GIT_SORT_TIME);
        git_revwalk_push_head(walk.get());
        git_revwalk_hide_glob(walk.get(), "tags/*");

        unique_git_obj_ptr obj(git_revparse_single, git_object_free, repo.get(), "HEAD~1000");
        git_revwalk_hide(walk.get(), git_object_id(obj.get()));

        git_oid oid;
        while (git_revwalk_next(&oid, walk.get()) == 0 && status != common::cmd_status::cancelled)
        {
            unique_commit_ptr commit(git_commit_lookup, git_commit_free, repo.get(), &oid);

            char oidstr[GIT_OID_HEXSZ + 1]{};
            std::string id(git_oid_tostr(oidstr, sizeof(oidstr), &oid));
            std::string message((git_commit_message(commit.get())));
            std::string author_email(git_commit_author(commit.get())->email);
            std::string author_name(git_commit_author(commit.get())->name);
            __time64_t timestamp = git_commit_time(commit.get());

            fons::git::commit commit_data(id, message, author_name, author_email, timestamp);
            queue_event<revwalk_event>(EVENT_REVWALK, EVENT_FOUND_COMMIT, commit_data);
        }

        return;
    }
} // namespace fons::git
```

I was interested in feedback on this code. Are there other ways to approach this problem I may not have considered? Or further ways to simplify the implementation? In particular I was wondering if there are ways to automatically deduce the template parameter for these pointers from the **foo arguments and eliminate the need for using alias statements.

Answer (score 2):

I’m not sure this is a good way to go about solving this problem.

The first thing that bothers me is that in order for this strategy to work, you have to almost entirely reimplement `std::unique_ptr`… all *just* to get customized behaviour in the constructor. That seems excessive.

It also puts the onus on you to make that re-implementation as good as the original… which, it ain’t. Let’s just pick on a single function to illustrate; let’s use `get()`:

```
// Your version's interface:
auto get() -> T*;

// std's interface:
auto get() const noexcept -> pointer;
```

Right away you can see that the standard version is superior, not only because it is guaranteed no-fail, but also because it can be used with a `const` instance.

Now you could go through and fix all these problems… but that would be missing the point. Trying to track the standard’s interface is a sucker’s game, because it can… has already… and probably will again in the future… change. Again, consider `get()`. The standard interface I gave above is valid for C++11—C++20… but as of C++23, it’s also going to be `constexpr`. Which means you’d have to use the preprocessor to check the standard version and conditionally add the `constexpr`.

But no, no, this is getting silly. So maybe trying to recreate `std::unique_ptr`’s interface isn’t the best plan.

The second thing that bothers me about this strategy is that will be very inefficient. The issue is in how you handle the deleter.

I actually don’t get why you’re using `std::function` at all in this case. It seems absurd. Just [compare the size of a unique pointer with a `std::function` deleter, versus one with a bare function pointer, versus one with a deleter type](https://godbolt.org/z/T3Go5T7MK). Using the bare function pointer—without `std::function`—makes it 2½× smaller. And there’s absolutely no benefit to using `std::function` here, because you *always* just use a plain C function as the deleter; never a lambda or bound function object or anything else that needs the extra storage `std::function` exists to manage.

But even the bare function pointer makes no sense, because you know, at compile time, what the deleter for any given type is. If `T` is a `git_repository`, then the deleter function is `git_repository_free()`. Always, always. Since that is statically known, there is no need for a function pointer to figure it out at runtime. Without the need for a function pointer, your unique pointer can be exactly the size of a bare pointer, with zero overhead when determining the deleter function.

So let me offer a first pass at an alternate strategy. Instead of trying to duplicate `std::unique_ptr` just to get a bespoke constructor, and instead of trying to muck about with function pointers to get custom deletion, how about this:

```
namespace fons::git {

struct deleter
{
    constexpr auto operator()(::git_commit* p) const noexcept { ::git_commit_free(p); }
    constexpr auto operator()(::git_revwalk* p) const noexcept { ::git_revwalk_free(p); }
    constexpr auto operator()(::git_object* p) const noexcept { ::git_object_free(p); }
    // ... and so on for every type and matching release function
};

} // namespace fons::git

// Usage example (bear with this for now):
::git_repository p = nullptr;

if (auto res = ::git_repository_open(&p, path); res != GIT_OK)
    throw some_error{};

auto repo = std::unique_ptr<::git_repository, fons::git::deleter>{p};
```

You could make it even nicer with a simple alias, and by taking advantage of template parameter deduction:

```
namespace fons::git {

struct deleter
{
    constexpr auto operator()(::git_commit* p) const noexcept { ::git_commit_free(p); }
    constexpr auto operator()(::git_revwalk* p) const noexcept { ::git_revwalk_free(p); }
    constexpr auto operator()(::git_object* p) const noexcept { ::git_object_free(p); }
    // ... and so on for every type and matching release function
};

template <typename T>
using unique_ptr = std::unique_ptr<T, deleter>;

} // namespace fons::git

// Usage example (bear with this for now):
::git_repository p = nullptr;

if (auto res = ::git_repository_open(&p, path); res != GIT_OK)
    throw some_error{};

auto repo = fons::git::unique_ptr{p};
```

But of course, that still leaves the ugliness of needing a temporary bare pointer, and the error handling.

The place to fix that, I would suggest, is not in the smart pointer, it is in a wrapper function around the problematic C function. For example:

```
namespace fons::git {

auto repository_open(char const* path) -> unique_ptr<::git_repository>;

// and, while we're at it, a handy overload so we don't need to do .c_str()
auto repository_open(std::filesystem::path const& path) -> unique_ptr<::git_repository>;

// and if you're storing paths as strings, i suppose you could use this, too
auto repository_open(std::string const& path) -> unique_ptr<::git_repository>;

} // namespace fons::git

// Usage example:
auto repo = fons::git::repository_open(path);

// and in case it isn't clear, repo is a
// std::unique_ptr<::git_repository, fons::git::deleter>
// which will be auto-released at the end of the scope.
```

The implementation of that wrapper function is trivial. In fact, we already wrote it:

```
auto repository_open(char const* path) -> unique_ptr<::git_repository>
{
    ::git_repository p = nullptr;

    if (auto res = ::git_repository_open(&p, path); res != GIT_OK)
        throw some_error{};

    return fons::git::unique_ptr{p};
}
```

What about the `some_error`? I’d recommend looking into `std::error_code`, making an error category for `libgit2`, and setting up the `system_error` machinery, so instead of `throw some_error{}`, you’d do `throw std::system_error{res, fons::git::error_category()}` (which, of course, could be simpler if you made an `enum` for git errors, yadda yadda… down to `throw std::system_error{fons::git::errc(res)}`; see a `system_error` tutorial for details). Then you could do like the filesystem library does, and have throwing and non-throwing functions:

```
namespace fons::git {

// will throw a std::system_error if opening the repo fails.
auto repository_open(char const* path) -> unique_ptr<::git_repository>;

// will *not* throw if opening the repo fails, but you can query ec
auto repository_open(char const* path, error_code& ec) -> unique_ptr<::git_repository>;

} // namespace fons::git

// Usage:

//  In this case, I'm *NOT* expecting the open to fail; if it does, that would be weird
//      auto repo = fons::git::repository_open(path);

//  In this case, I *EXPECT* the open to fail, sometimes
//      auto ec = std::error_code{};
//      auto repo = fons::git::repository_open(path, ec);
//      if (not ec)
//          // open was okay
//      else
//          // handle error; ec contains details about error
```

In practice, I’d use the simpler version when I wasn’t really expecting problems, and if a repo fails to open, I could just catch the exception at a higher level and report via message box or something. I’d use the `error_code` version when a failure isn’t entirely unlikely, and I have a strategy for what to do if one happens (like, maybe try an alternate path, or try a recovery, or whatever). (Or if you *really* want to get high-tech, don’t make the same mistake the standard filesystem library did, with its double interface, and maybe look into `expected`, or `outcome`, or LEAF, or whatever else instead.)

But in all this the bottom line is: there is no need to roll your own smart pointer. All the standard pointers will work just fine. Just pass your custom deleter—and use a *type*, not function pointers—and you can use `unique_ptr`, `shared_ptr`, whatever.

The place to handle all that error-handling logic isn’t in a *pointer* constructor, it’s in wrappers around the clunky C functions. Which are a good idea anyway, because you can fix all the other bad C interface crap (like using strings instead of `char const*`).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write out such detailed feedback, I'll definitely be incorporating this!

I had hopped to avoid writing wrapper code for the libgit2 functions, but I think your recommendation will save me time as I start putting comprehensive error handling into the code, and run into other recurring issues that come with working with c-style libraries. The construction error-handling found its way into the pointer constructor as a way to avoid rewriting boilerplate code each time a libgit2 object is created. I think by templating wrapper code I can achieve something similar